# Ошибка при попытки использования dagger2 для генерации файлов

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

Прошёлся уже по всем форумам - ничего не помогает.

Возникает ошибка:

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

В dependencies у меня:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.48.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.43.2")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
...
```

В плагинах:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}
```

Код(AppComponent.kt):

```
import dagger.Component

@Component
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(activity: Activity)
}
```

Код(Activity .kt):

```
import javax.inject.Inject
class Activity {
    @Inject
    lateinit var keyboard: Keyboard
}
```

Код(Keyboard.kt):

```
class Keyboard @Inject constructor() {
}
```

Comment: Версии самого Даггера и компилятора различаются у вас.